# How do I group entry timestamps into visitor-specific "sessions" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, web-analytics

Here's some mock data:

```
visitor_id,channel,timestamp,order_id,session
100,A,1,,1
100,B,2,,1
100,A,3,,1
100,B,4,1,1
100,B,5,,2
100,B,6,,2
100,B,7,2,2
100,A,8,,3
100,A,9,,3
```

A visitor will come into the site via channels, and eventually order (creating an order_id). Many visitors never order, but I still want to group their session together (to determine what was their first channel, for example). The last column is one example solving the problem.

What's an efficient, declarative statement to create it in PostgreSQL? Are there better solutions than what I am proposing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine the values up-to an order.  One method would be to assign each row a grouping id, such as the number of orders before a given time.  This can be done with a correlated subquery:

```
select md.*,
       (select count(md2.order_id)
        from mockdata md2
        where md2.visitor_id = md.visitor_id and
              md2.timestamp < md.timestamp
       ) as session
from mockdata md;
```

This can also be done using a cumulative count:

```
select md.*,
       count(order_id) over (partition by visitor_id
                             order by timestamp
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                            ) as session
from mockdata md;
```

Comment: I tried both on a 3 million row table on an AWS RDS db.r3.large instance, the correlated subquery (as expected) didn't terminate before my timeout, the second completed in 26 seconds. This highly fuzzy and anecdotal performance test prefers the second solution.